# Create html page with password that leads to various html pages depending on the user

Tags: passwords

I have an HTML page with the form fields for username and password. My goal is to have 3 different users, and each user that logs in will be directed to one of 3 different html pages. I need the simplest solution. I don't know how to use databases, I've used .htaccess and password generators like: http://shop.alterlinks.com/htpasswd/htpasswd.php

I prefer if there was an just a code I can simply copy and paste into my HTML page or something simple like this. 
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: `"code I can simply copy and paste"` - Without knowing or caring what that code does or how it does it?  That's a *very* dangerous practice.

Comment: Of course I care and know enough to spot dangers. I just don't know enough to do it by myself. :/

Comment: I'm not sure if this functionality can be meaningfully achieved with just HTML and things like `htaccess`, to be honest. Having some kind of server-side code and a login system is probably actually the simplest solution. If the data is *never going to change* (or if a re-deployment is ok for a data change) then you don't need to use a database, you can hard-code the values. You'd simply accept the login input, compare it with known values (please use hashed passwords even in this setup), and on successful login forward the user to the known page (which itself checks if the user is logged in).

Comment: Did you see [dynamic url using form field value](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/comments/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12818) on your Google search?  If you want pure HTML, have your usual .htpasswd file protecting each subdirectory, preferably using SHA-512 with a lot of iterations, and only have the username on the form.  Then the system will as for username (again) and password for .htpasswd.  There's some [primitive offline .htpasswd scripts in the nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Faq); if you use that online generator, then they can already have all your passwords!  Maybe they share them.